# Add More Than One Web Domains in Facebook Console

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing the FB login/logout in my web apps. Each of my web apps serves a different purpose thus having different domains. But they share the same user database.

User's Facebook sign-up comes from one web app. I pass the access token returned by the client side `JS-SDK` login function to the server. At server side I used the Facebook email and ID (retrieved with graph API `/me`) as the user's username and password, respectively.

At first, I created a unique Facebook **App** for each of my web sites. In this case, in my other web apps, when logging in with Facebook, the graph API `/me` returns a different ID for the same user, so the user cannot login.

It turns out that the `response.authResponse.accessToken` returned by Facebook login is also different. Then I tried to add all the domains under `Settings->Advanced->Valid OAuth redirect URIs` in one Website App, but the access token and ID are still different for each domain.

I wonder what is the problem here. Why Facebook returns different IDs for the same user. And why the access token is different even if the web domains are all in one App (same app ID and secret). Thanks.

Comment: They are different user ids because they are app scoped user ids. How to map users between your different apps you can read about at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: @WizKid I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WizKid suggested [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business), you need to map users between different apps. Usually you will need to create a Business Manager and add your apps to that manager. Then you'll have access to all the apps' info, including their scoped user IDs, by calling API `/me/ids_for_business`